# Advice: 2008 Mac w/OSX 10.8 host w/Virtualbox guest Ubuntu 12.04 setting up python, scikit-learn & other ML tools

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.x, osx-mountain-lion, virtualbox, scikit-learn

I would like feedback on what options, or best options I have for what I need to accomplish.  I have an older Macbook pro 2008, 8GB RAM, 10.8 Mountain Lion.  I installed Virtualbox and have Ubuntu 12.04 VM setup.  The reason for the Ubuntu install was to be able to run some perl scripts I needed to gather data and put them into a MongoDB (I could not do this in OSX)

From the MongoDB, I will extract data into formats that I can input into open source machine learning libraries.. one I want to start with is scikit-learn. Others could be WEKA, and small scale Hadoop (as Hadoop is something I want to start learning to use as well, so I would kill two birds with one stone).  maybe even graphlab...

The amount of data is not very large, in raw form before Mongo, its about 3-4GB total now.

Since I had the Ubuntu VM, I decided to use that for running scikit learn.  I installed python3 on Ubuntu, then numpy, scipy, matplotlib, then scikitlearn.  When I run the nosetests, I get errors and FAILED.

I have read about various options and am not sure whats the best way to proceed.  do I use one of the prepackaged tools for either Ubuntu or on OSX to be able to run scikit learn and python3?  such as: EPD Entought Canopy  OR http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkgs.html OR for OSX https://github.com/fonnesbeck/ScipySuperpack

do I forget about python3 and use python 2.7 and install everything with that from source..?  Which, Ubuntu or OSX, would be the best choice for using scikit learn and other popular free machine learning libraries/tools?

thanks in advance for the help and time.

Below is the output from running *nosetests sklearn --exe* It is the trail end of the output.   Due to the character limit and as that has the errors, the first part has mostly warnings..

```
./usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/datasets/tests/test_base.py:155: UserWarning: Could not load sample images, PIL is not available.
/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/decomposition/fastica_.py:271: UserWarning: Ignoring n_components with whiten=False.
./usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py:75: DeprecationWarning: Class ProbabilisticPCA is deprecated; ProbabilisticPCA will be removed in 0.16. WARNING: the covariance estimation was previously incorrect, your output might be different  than under the previous versions. Use PCA that implements score and score_samples. To work with homoscedastic=False, you should use FactorAnalysis.

/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/test/test_func_inspect.py:122: UserWarning: Cannot inspect object functools.partial(<function f at 0xba47dec>, 1), ignore list will not work.
  nose.tools.assert_equal(filter_args(ff, ['y'], (1, )),
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: SyntaxError (invalid syntax (test_text.py, line 561))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/failure.py", line 38, in runTest
    raise self.exc_val.with_traceback(self.tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/loader.py", line 413, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/tests/test_text.py", line 561
    expected_stop_words = set([u'celeri', u'tomato', u'copyright', u'coke',
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

======================================================================
ERROR: sklearn.metrics.tests.test_metrics.test_classification_report_multiclass_with_string_label
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/tests/test_metrics.py", line 822, in test_classification_report_multiclass_with_string_label
    report = classification_report(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/metrics.py", line 1828, in classification_report
    average=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/metrics.py", line 1550, in precision_recall_fscore_support
    'precision', 'predicted', average)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/metrics.py", line 1331, in _prf_divide
    result = numerator / denominator
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3) (4) 

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: SyntaxError (invalid syntax (test_multiclass.py, line 53))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/failure.py", line 38, in runTest
    raise self.exc_val.with_traceback(self.tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/loader.py", line 413, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/tests/test_multiclass.py", line 53
    np.array([u'a', u'b', u'c']),
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

======================================================================
ERROR: sklearn.tests.test_common.test_all_estimators
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/tests/test_common.py", line 58, in test_all_estimators
    estimators = all_estimators(include_meta_estimators=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/testing.py", line 300, in all_estimators
    module = __import__(modname, fromlist="dummy")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/tests/test_text.py", line 561
    expected_stop_words = set([u'celeri', u'tomato', u'copyright', u'coke',
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

======================================================================
ERROR: sklearn.tests.test_common.test_all_estimator_no_base_class
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/tests/test_common.py", line 117, in test_all_estimator_no_base_class
    for name, Estimator in all_estimators():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/testing.py", line 300, in all_estimators
    module = __import__(modname, fromlist="dummy")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/tests/test_text.py", line 561
    expected_stop_words = set([u'celeri', u'tomato', u'copyright', u'coke',
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

======================================================================
ERROR: sklearn.tests.test_common.test_estimators_sparse_data
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/tests/test_common.py", line 131, in test_estimators_sparse_data
    estimators = all_estimators()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/testing.py", line 300, in all_estimators
    module = __import__(modname, fromlist="dummy")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/tests/test_text.py", line 561
    expected_stop_words = set([u'celeri', u'tomato', u'copyright', u'coke',
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

======================================================================
ERROR: sklearn.tests.test_common.test_transformers_sparse_data
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/tests/test_common.py", line 258, in test_transformers_sparse_data
    estimators = all_estimators(type_filter='transformer')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/testing.py", line 300, in all_estimators
    module = __import__(modname, fromlist="dummy")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/tests/test_text.py", line 561
    expected_stop_words = set([u'celeri', u'tomato', u'copyright', u'coke',
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

======================================================================
ERROR: sklearn.tests.test_common.test_estimators_nan_inf
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/tests/test_common.py", line 301, in test_estimators_nan_inf
    estimators = all_estimators()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/testing.py", line 300, in all_estimators
    module = __import__(modname, fromlist="dummy")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/tests/test_text.py", line 561
    expected_stop_words = set([u'celeri', u'tomato', u'copyright', u'coke',
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

======================================================================
ERROR: sklearn.tests.test_common.test_transformers_pickle
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/tests/test_common.py", line 392, in test_transformers_pickle
    transformers = all_estimators(type_filter='transformer')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/testing.py", line 300, in all_estimators
    module = __import__(modname, fromlist="dummy")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/tests/test_text.py", line 561
    expected_stop_words = set([u'celeri', u'tomato', u'copyright', u'coke',
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

======================================================================
ERROR: sklearn.tests.test_common.test_classifiers_one_label
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/tests/test_common.py", line 457, in test_classifiers_one_label
    classifiers = all_estimators(type_filter='classifier')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/testing.py", line 300, in all_estimators
    module = __import__(modname, fromlist="dummy")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/tests/test_text.py", line 561
    expected_stop_words = set([u'celeri', u'tomato', u'copyright', u'coke',
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

======================================================================
ERROR: sklearn.tests.test_common.test_clustering
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/tests/test_common.py", line 492, in test_clustering
    clustering = all_estimators(type_filter='cluster')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/testing.py", line 300, in all_estimators
    module = __import__(modname, fromlist="dummy")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/tests/test_text.py", line 561
    expected_stop_words = set([u'celeri', u'tomato', u'copyright', u'coke',
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

======================================================================
ERROR: sklearn.tests.test_common.test_classifiers_train
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/tests/test_common.py", line 530, in test_classifiers_train
    classifiers = all_estimators(type_filter='classifier')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/testing.py", line 300, in all_estimators
    module = __import__(modname, fromlist="dummy")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/tests/test_text.py", line 561
    expected_stop_words = set([u'celeri', u'tomato', u'copyright', u'coke',
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

======================================================================
ERROR: sklearn.tests.test_common.test_classifiers_classes
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/tests/test_common.py", line 605, in test_classifiers_classes
    classifiers = all_estimators(type_filter='classifier')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/testing.py", line 300, in all_estimators
    module = __import__(modname, fromlist="dummy")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/tests/test_text.py", line 561
    expected_stop_words = set([u'celeri', u'tomato', u'copyright', u'coke',
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

======================================================================
ERROR: sklearn.tests.test_common.test_classifiers_input_shapes
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/tests/test_common.py", line 650, in test_classifiers_input_shapes
    classifiers = all_estimators(type_filter='classifier')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/testing.py", line 300, in all_estimators
    module = __import__(modname, fromlist="dummy")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/tests/test_text.py", line 561
    expected_stop_words = set([u'celeri', u'tomato', u'copyright', u'coke',
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

======================================================================
ERROR: sklearn.tests.test_common.test_classifiers_pickle
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/tests/test_common.py", line 691, in test_classifiers_pickle
    classifiers = all_estimators(type_filter='classifier')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/testing.py", line 300, in all_estimators
    module = __import__(modname, fromlist="dummy")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/tests/test_text.py", line 561
    expected_stop_words = set([u'celeri', u'tomato', u'copyright', u'coke',
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

======================================================================
ERROR: sklearn.tests.test_common.test_regressors_int
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/tests/test_common.py", line 749, in test_regressors_int
    regressors = all_estimators(type_filter='regressor')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/testing.py", line 300, in all_estimators
    module = __import__(modname, fromlist="dummy")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/tests/test_text.py", line 561
    expected_stop_words = set([u'celeri', u'tomato', u'copyright', u'coke',
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

======================================================================
ERROR: sklearn.tests.test_common.test_regressors_train
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/tests/test_common.py", line 780, in test_regressors_train
    regressors = all_estimators(type_filter='regressor')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/testing.py", line 300, in all_estimators
    module = __import__(modname, fromlist="dummy")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/tests/test_text.py", line 561
    expected_stop_words = set([u'celeri', u'tomato', u'copyright', u'coke',
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

======================================================================
ERROR: sklearn.tests.test_common.test_regressor_pickle
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/tests/test_common.py", line 823, in test_regressor_pickle
    regressors = all_estimators(type_filter='regressor')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/testing.py", line 300, in all_estimators
    module = __import__(modname, fromlist="dummy")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/tests/test_text.py", line 561
    expected_stop_words = set([u'celeri', u'tomato', u'copyright', u'coke',
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

======================================================================
ERROR: sklearn.tests.test_common.test_class_weight_classifiers
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/tests/test_common.py", line 889, in test_class_weight_classifiers
    classifiers = all_estimators(type_filter='classifier')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/testing.py", line 300, in all_estimators
    module = __import__(modname, fromlist="dummy")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/tests/test_text.py", line 561
    expected_stop_words = set([u'celeri', u'tomato', u'copyright', u'coke',
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

======================================================================
ERROR: sklearn.tests.test_common.test_class_weight_auto_classifies
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/tests/test_common.py", line 926, in test_class_weight_auto_classifies
    classifiers = all_estimators(type_filter='classifier')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/testing.py", line 300, in all_estimators
    module = __import__(modname, fromlist="dummy")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/tests/test_text.py", line 561
    expected_stop_words = set([u'celeri', u'tomato', u'copyright', u'coke',
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

======================================================================
ERROR: sklearn.tests.test_common.test_estimators_overwrite_params
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/tests/test_common.py", line 974, in test_estimators_overwrite_params
    estimators = all_estimators(type_filter=est_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/testing.py", line 300, in all_estimators
    module = __import__(modname, fromlist="dummy")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/tests/test_text.py", line 561
    expected_stop_words = set([u'celeri', u'tomato', u'copyright', u'coke',
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

======================================================================
ERROR: sklearn.tests.test_common.test_cluster_overwrite_params
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/tests/test_common.py", line 1018, in test_cluster_overwrite_params
    clusterers = all_estimators(type_filter="cluster")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/testing.py", line 300, in all_estimators
    module = __import__(modname, fromlist="dummy")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/tests/test_text.py", line 561
    expected_stop_words = set([u'celeri', u'tomato', u'copyright', u'coke',
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

======================================================================
FAIL: Test confusion matrix - binary classification case
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/tests/test_metrics.py", line 630, in test_confusion_matrix_binary
    [str(y) for y in y_pred])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/tests/test_metrics.py", line 625, in test
    assert_array_almost_equal(mcc, true_mcc, decimal=2)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/testing/utils.py", line 800, in assert_array_almost_equal
    header=('Arrays are not almost equal to %d decimals' % decimal))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/testing/utils.py", line 636, in assert_array_compare
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: 
Arrays are not almost equal to 2 decimals

(mismatch 100.0%)
 x: array(0.6011393316693135)
 y: array(0.5715476066494083)

======================================================================
FAIL: sklearn.metrics.tests.test_metrics.test_classification_report_multiclass_with_unicode_label
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/tests/test_metrics.py", line 856, in test_classification_report_multiclass_with_unicode_label
    assert_equal(report, expected_report)
AssertionError: '             precision    recall  f1-score   support\n\n      blue¢       0.63  [truncated]... != '             precision    recall  f1-score   support\n\n      blue¢       0.83  [truncated]...
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

-       blue¢       0.63      0.33      0.44        36
-      green¢       0.17      0.17      0.17         6
+       blue¢       0.83      0.79      0.81        24
+      green¢       0.33      0.10      0.15        31
         red¢       0.42      0.90      0.57        20

- avg / total       0.52      0.50      0.45        62
?                      ^         ^          ----------
+ avg / total       0.51      0.53      0.47        75
?                      ^         ^         ++++++++++


======================================================================
FAIL: Ensure that classification metrics with string labels
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.2.egg/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/tests/test_metrics.py", line 1177, in test_invariance_string_vs_numbers_labels
    "test".format(name))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/testing/utils.py", line 707, in assert_array_equal
    verbose=verbose, header='Arrays are not equal')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/testing/utils.py", line 636, in assert_array_compare
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: 
Arrays are not equal
precision_score failed string vs number invariance test
(mismatch 100.0%)
 x: array(0.85)
 y: array(0.6666666666666666)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1714 tests in 129.977s

FAILED (SKIP=16, errors=23, failures=3)
```

Comment: I read a post stating that it does not make much difference to use python 2.7 vs python 3.  My reason for using python 3 was to learn and work with what is the newest and I assume replacing python 2.7.  So if I go with python 2.7, I can use one of the pre-built packages or still build from source.  That being said, is Ubuntu VM going to be better to use vs OSX (my actual OS and host)?

Comment: Please just report the traceback of the error message if you want us to help you find the source of the problem.

Comment: I'd recommend either using anaconda on OS X for python 2.7. What is the virtual box for?

Comment: ogrisel - I edited the post with the output errors, thank you.  Andreas - I needed Ubuntu or to be able to run perl scripts for gathering and storing the data into MongoDB.  I could not run them on OSX.  I have read good things about anaconda.  I will try that out.

Comment: You're running an outdated scikit-learn version that did not yet support Python3. Upgrade to 0.14.

Comment: larsman - I used the bleeding edge version (via github) in my Ubuntu VM.  Now, I d/l the stable 0.14, built, installed with python3.  With the install, I get 2 invalid syntax errors. I ran nosetests and get `code` Ran 1562 tests in 95.474s

FAILED (SKIP=13, errors=31, failures=3)

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.2 is not (yet?) supported as written on the [README.rst](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/README.rst) file of the project on github. Please install Python 3.3 or stick to Python 2.7 for now.